# CHM (Windows Help) file viewer with good search

Tags: windows, documentation-viewer

The Windows builtin viewer (looks the same as in 1995) has very bad search. It show the page that has the match, but does not scroll to the part where the match is, also there is no "view next match" feature.

I'm looking for a viewer that has a decent search feature. Target OS is Windows.

PS: I noticed that in Window HTML Help viewer, in the search results, if I click into the content, I can use ctrl+f to bring up a search dialog to search thru the page. I still prefer a better app, since for example searching for "additional" will also find "addition". Basically, the search is horrible.

Comment: most text searchers need to match by character so will start with a in abc then match on ab not a.*c which is when you need a "regex" text filter. However if you type abc most searchers will not match on a or ab only abc search this HTML page  with `additional` should only find the 2 examples and not the two in addition unless you are typing key by key at that time in which case the will be 4 in addition to this one=5. remember the problem with CHM is it is just Compressed HM so not easy for plain text filters. Have you tried an app such as AgentRansack (pro version)